# Expected value of $E\left[Y|X\right]$ with 3 random variables $X$ and $Y$ and $Z$ and the $MSE$ of it

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, mean-square-error

Okay, the information we have:
$Z$~$N(0,1)$
$Z$ is statistic independent of $X$
$Y=\begin{cases}a\left|X\right|&Z\ge 0\\ b\left|X\right|&Z<0\end{cases}$
We know that $X$ is a continuous random variable that $P\left(-1\le X\le 1\right)=1$ and $f_X\left(x\right)<\infty$ and $E[X]=\mu$ and $Var[X]=\sigma^2$
I have to find $$\hat{Y\:}_{opt}\left(X\right)=E\left[Y|X\right]$$

To be honest, I do not know how to start.
Thought maybe separating to $X\ge0$ and $X\le0$ and then do: $E\left[Y|X\right]=E\left[Y|X\ge 0\right]+E\left[Y|X<0\right]$
But I do not know if it is allowed or how to continue with it.
I don't think I have to use Law of total expectation since I will have two dependency and I don't know if it possible to solve it?
I guess the $MSE$ I can solve afterwards since it is just $MSE\left\{\hat{Y\:}_{opt}\left(X\right)\right\}=E\left[\left(Y-\hat{Y\:}_{opt}\left(X\right)\right)^2\right]$ .
But my problem is finding $\hat{Y\:}_{opt}\left(X\right)$
Any clues will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I do not know if it is allowed or how to continue with it.

You know the law of total expectation, apply it to the conditional expectation:

$$E[Y|X] = E[ E[Y|X,U]]$$ where $U=1$ if $Z \ge 0$, $U=0$ otherwise, and the outer expectation is wrt to $U$.

Now, $E[Y|X,U=1] = a |X|$ and  $E[Y|X,U=0] = b |X|$ , which we can writen as

$$ E[Y|X,U] = |X| [ a U + b(1-U) ]  $$

Can you go on from here?

Comment: Understood almost all, just a little something. the last part, why is the expected value of that is what you received? How did you do that expected value? And the question is, how do I play with $U$if its just a indicator of $Z$?  I need to express $U$ as $Z$ at the end, which is the problem here... How is: $E\left[E\left[Y|X,U=1\right]\right]=E\left[a\left|X\right|\right]=aE\left[\left|X\right|\right]=f\left(X\right)\cdot U???$ the $f(X)$, where did $U$ come from? it does not heve dependency on $X$

Comment: $E\left[X|Y\right]=E_{_{Z|Y}}\left[E\left[X|Y,Z\right]|Y\right]$....... Should it not be like that also? the formula for the expanded law of total expectation

Comment: I'm not sure I get you. My eq $(2)$ simply expresses in a single formula the two cases ($U=0$ and $U=1$).

Comment: yea but how you reach it $E\left[Y|X,U\right]=\left|X\right|\left(\left(1-U\right)a+Ub\right)$ I did not understand it...... I understand the two cases of $U=0$ and $U=1$, but how did you "sum" them exactly to the original?  Regarding the formula I said, is it not true what I said? at the second comment, with the formula of expanded law of total expectation

Ohhh, you just wrote it in general, I understand now

Comment: That is what I have at my courses, the expanded one, but you wrote a different formula for the expanded one.

Comment: Okay, did I understand correctly? $E_{{U|X}}\left[\left[\left|X\right|\left(\left(1-U\right)a+Ub\right)\right]|X\right]$ is equal to $E_{U}\left[\left[\left|X\right|\left(\left(1-U\right)a+Ub\right)\right]|X\right]$ which is equal to $E_{U}\left[\left[\left|X\right|\left(\left(1-U\right)a+Ub\right)\right]\right]$ and then we know $E\left[U\right]=\frac{1}{2}$ and thus the equation is $\left|X\right|\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)a+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)b\right)$

Comment: I think that's right

Comment: Wow, thanks!!! did not think I would have understood it!!

Comment: Just one think to make sure, it should be $E\left[Y|X,U\right]=\left|X\right|\left[\left(1-U\right)b+\left(U\right)a\right]$ no? since if $U=1$ so we get $a|X|$ but according to your we get $b|X|$

Comment: YOu are right, fixed

Answer (score 1):

$$E\left[Y|X\right]=E\left[a\left|X\right|I_{Z\geq 0}+b\left|X\right|I_{Z\leq 0}\mid X\right]=\left|X\right|E\left[aI_{Z\geq 0}+bI_{Z\leq 0}\right]=\frac{a+b}{2}|X|$$
$$Var(Y|X)=E[Y^2|X]-E[Y|X]^2=\frac{(a-b)^2}{4}X^2$$

Comment: Oh actually I did not have to find that $Var$ but its good for me to check for the solution for my $MSE$ since the $MSE$ is :$MSE=E\left[\left(\hat{Y\:}_{opt}\left(X\right)-Y\right)^2\right]$ and I received $MSE=\left(\sigma ^2+\mu ^2\right)\left(\frac{a+b-2ab}{2}\right)$ So I will check and update, Thanks ( in like 30min~hour )

Comment: Oh I did not actually calculate $Var(Y|X)$, but I did something else, but it looks like Its close to what I did for the MSE. I guess I did okay, thanks!!