# Finding $MSE$ of optimal estimator

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, fourier-series, estimation, mean-square-error

**Background of the question:**
We know that $X$ is a continuous random variable that has $P\left(-1\le X\le 1\right)=1$
and $f_X\left(x\right)<\infty $
We define $X(n)=cos(\pi n X)$
$E[X]=\mu$ and $Var[X]=\sigma ^2$
We found in previous sections:
$E\left[X\left(n\right)\right]=\int _{-1}^1f_X\left(x\right)cos\left(\pi nx\right)dx$
$X(n)$ is not W.S.S
We had another random variable $Z$ which is $Y=\begin{cases}a\left|X\right|&Z\ge 0\\ b\left|X\right|&Z<0\end{cases}$ and $Z$~$N(0,1)$
$Z$ is statistic independent of $X$
**We found:**
$\hat{Y}_{opt}\left(X\right)=\left|X\right|\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$
$MSE\left\{\hat{Y\:}_{opt}\left(X\right)\right\}=E\left[\left(\hat{Y\:}_{opt}\left(X\right)-Y\right)^2\right]=\left(\sigma ^2+\mu ^2\right)\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)^2$
**Showing how I reached the MSE:**
$E\left[\left(\hat{Y}_{opt}\left(X\right)-Y\right)^2\right]=E\left[\left(\left|X\right|\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)-Y\right)^2\right]=E\left[\left|X\right|^2\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2-2Y\left|X\right|\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)+Y^2\right]=\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2E\left[X^2\right]-\left(a+b\right)E\left[Y\left|X\right|\right]+E\left[Y^2\right]=\left(\sigma^2+\mu^2\right)\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)^2$
Regarding how I proved the optimal estimator, I did it the same was as where I got help here [Expected value of $E\left[Y|X\right]$ with 3 random variables $X$ and $Y$ and $Z$ and the $MSE$ of it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4865674/expected-value-of-e-leftyx-right-with-3-random-variables-x-and-y-and-z/4865756#4865756)
Just without dependency, its basically the same, using law of expected value
My assumptions here were:
Its true since $|X|^2$=$X^2$ and also $X\cdot\left|X\right|=X^2$
Thanks to Fred Li I realized my assumptions are wrong, now I will try to fix the second part at the expected value, since $X\cdot\left|X\right|\ne X^2$

**What I need to prove:**
We need to prove that the best estimator of $Y$ from samples of {$X(n)$}$_{_{_{n=0,1,...}}}$ is linear, which means:
$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:a_nX\left(n\right)$ with $\left\{a_n\right\}_{_{_{n=0,1,..}}}$
We need to find $a_n$ as functions of $f_X(x)$ and find the MSE of the $\hat{Y}_{opt}\left(X\right)$ using $a$,$b$,$\mu$,$\sigma$

***My try:***
since $\hat{Y}_{opt}\left(X\right)=\left|X\right|\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$
We can define $g(X)$ such that:
$g\left(X\right):=\left|X\right|\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$
We see that $g(X)$ is even, continuous at $[-1,1]$, thus she has expansion of Fourier series with $cos$ only
And for that reason, the Fourier series of $g(X)$: $\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:a_ncos\left(\pi nX\right)$ converges to $g(X)$ at $L^2$
We see that this estimator is a function of $X$.
thus, all we have to do is it achieves the same $MSE$ as the optimal estimator.
Which means basically:
$$E\left[\left(\hat{Y\:}_{_{lin}}\left(X\right)-\hat{Y\:}_{opt}\left(X\right)\right)^2\right]=0$$
**Problem:**
That is my problem here, I do not really know how to prove it, although it should be right.
Finding the coefficient of the fourier series $a_n$ is not hard, just like finding fourier coefficients, but my problem is with the $MSE$

Any ideas will be appreciated!!

Comment: The MSE formula for $\hat{Y}_{opt}(X)$ does not look right.

Comment: Are you sure? I Compared with a friend and we both got the same ( And we solved it not together, just compared it ). We both are stuck at that section ( last one ). I did it like that: $MSE\left\{\hat{Y}_{opt}\left(X\right)\right\}=E\left[\left(\hat{Y\:}_{opt}\left(X\right)-Y\right)^2\right]$

Comment: Oh dam, I just noticed, I forgot to multiply the square on the first expression also... How did my and my friend reach same concolusion. I will fix it right away! BRB

Comment: Another note: the condition that $E[X]=\mu$ does not lead to $E[|X|]=\mu$, since $X$ can be negative. Therefore it is not clear to me how you can derive the MSE formula.

Comment: I will edit my way of solution here, I just updated the new MSE according to the solution, sorry, forgot to square the constants at the beginning, I will update in a few minutes with the calculation.

Comment: @FredLi Fixed it and showed the steps, its basically from another post I uploaded since the beginning was really impossible for me, but afterwards I did the same idea for the others and reached that conclusion.

Comment: @FredLi Added another thing at the edit: $|X|^2=X^2$ and $|X| * X=X^2$, that was my assumption, I just realized by that negative $X$, I did wrong assumption.. $|X| * X$ is $-X^2$, ow... But anyway, regarding the question itself, What can I do to find that expected value? I will try to fix my before $MSE$.

Comment: Now I understand why you said that calculating the expected value of the absolute value of $X$, its impossible, since the $\mu$ is for $X$ and  not for $|X|$, so I cant calculate $E[X|X|]$, I will keep it aside for now since its less problematic, I will try to ask my professor if the question is in wrong here. But I want to focus on my original question.

Comment: I guess the expectation you would like to prove is implied by the $L_2$-convergence of the Fourier series, but the $L_2$-norm is defined w.r.t. the probability measure of $X$ instead of Lebesgue. You have shown that under the Lebesgue measure, you have $L_2$-convergence, so I guess multiplying a bounded density in the integrand there should not change this convergence...?

Comment: @FredLi Hi, yea, multiplying by a bounded should not change the convergence, I hope I am not wrong, but yea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but the following claim seems to hold true.  For any square-integrable even function $g(x)>0$ defined on $[-1,1]$, its Fourier series converges in $L_2$ by the Riesz-Fischer theorem:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-1}^1\Big(g(x) - \sum_{n=0}^Na_n \cos(n\pi x) \Big)^2dx= 0.  $$
Then, let $X$ denote a random variable with a continuous density function $f_X(x)<K$ defined on $[-1,1]$. The boundedness of $f_X(x)$ directly leads to the following result, which hopefully should solve your problem:
$$  E\left[\Big(g(X) - \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \cos(n\pi X) \Big)^2\right] =\lim_{N\to\infty} E\left[\Big(g(X) - \sum_{n=0}^Na_n \cos(n\pi X) \Big)^2\right]\\
=\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-1}^1\Big(g(x) - \sum_{n=0}^N a_n \cos(n\pi x) \Big)^2f(x)dx\leq \lim_{N\to\infty} K\int_{-1}^1\Big(g(x) - \sum_{n=0}^N a_n \cos(n\pi x) \Big)^2dx=0. $$

Comment: Hi, Regarding your answer, to be honest, I don't know that Riesz-Fischer theorem, but I was taught that at Fourier analysis 1year ago,  but not by name, just definition. Regarding what you did, you assume that the expected value of the first part is bigger than zero because the expression is positive only? $E\left[\left(g\left(X\right)-\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:a_ncos\left(\pi nX\right)\right)^2\right]\ge 0$ So from showing them both, we can assume $E\left[\left(g\left(X\right)-\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:a_ncos\left(\pi nX\right)\right)^2\right]=0$ and thus we proved what I had to, right?

Comment: Yes you are correct. MSE is always non-negative, since MSE is in essence an integral with a non-negative integrand.

Comment: Thanks!! Finally could finish the assignment, that one question was the reason I could not submit a 40 page assignment :\